# Using numpy and pandas how to calculate percentage and using criteria and give it negative sign

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have data like this :

```
A   B
25  50
25  25
50  25
75  100
80  100
100 80
```

I want to calculate percentage, for column  B how many % highest than A.
So, % = (B-A)*100,

But, When B is smaller than A, then I want to display -negative sign (i.e -50%). Because I want only B how many % > A .

If B is less than A then it will show 0 or - negative sign percentage numbers.

For example : A=50 , B=25, then (B/A)*100 = -50% or 0 %

[image]
Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) or [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['C'] = (df['B'] / df['A']) * 100
df['D'] = df['C'].mask((df['B'] < df['A']), df['C'] * -1)
print (df)
     A    B           C           D
0   25   50  200.000000  200.000000
1   25   25  100.000000  100.000000
2   50   25   50.000000  -50.000000
3   75  100  133.333333  133.333333
4   80  100  125.000000  125.000000
5  100   80   80.000000  -80.000000
```

```
df['C'] = df['B'].div(df['A']).mul(100)
df['D'] = df['C'].mask((df['B'] < df['A']), df['C'].mul(-1))
print (df)
     A    B           C           D
0   25   50  200.000000  200.000000
1   25   25  100.000000  100.000000
2   50   25   50.000000  -50.000000
3   75  100  133.333333  133.333333
4   80  100  125.000000  125.000000
5  100   80   80.000000  -80.000000
```

---

```
df['D'] = np.where((df['B'] < df['A']), df['C'] * -1, df['C'])
print (df)
     A    B           C           D
0   25   50  200.000000  200.000000
1   25   25  100.000000  100.000000
2   50   25   50.000000  -50.000000
3   75  100  133.333333  133.333333
4   80  100  125.000000  125.000000
5  100   80   80.000000  -80.000000
```

Comment: Glad can help, nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Using `eval` with some logic

```
df.eval('C = ((B >= A) * 2 - 1) * B / A * 100', inplace=False)

     A    B           C
0   25   50  200.000000
1   25   25  100.000000
2   50   25  -50.000000
3   75  100  133.333333
4   80  100  125.000000
5  100   80  -80.000000
```

Without `eval`

```
df.assign(C=((df.B >= df.A) * 2 - 1) * df.B / df.A * 100)

     A    B           C
0   25   50  200.000000
1   25   25  100.000000
2   50   25  -50.000000
3   75  100  133.333333
4   80  100  125.000000
5  100   80  -80.000000
```

With `numpy`

```
B = df.B.values
A = df.A.values
df.assign(C=((B >= A) * 2 - 1) * B / A * 100)

     A    B           C
0   25   50  200.000000
1   25   25  100.000000
2   50   25  -50.000000
3   75  100  133.333333
4   80  100  125.000000
5  100   80  -80.000000
```